# while(cin >> x), what is the boolean value here?

Tags: c++

What is checked in the following condition:

```
 while(cin >> x)
```

to have a while loop continue going? What's the boolean value of an expression assignment in the code above?

Answer (score 1):

The expression result of `cin >> x` is a reference to the `cin` stream, a `std::istream`.

A `std::istream` *effectively* converts to boolean when used as an `if` or `while` condition expression.

The result is equivalent to writing

`!cin.fail()`.

---

In C++03 the conversion was technically an `operator void*()`.

That, however, was not so nice with respect to overload resolution and some other issues.

So in C++11 it's an `explicit operator bool()`. The keyword `explicit` could only be used on constructors in C++03, but in C++11 it can also be applied to conversion operators. It prevents the usual inadvertent implicit conversions, but as a special case it is effectively ignored for conversion to boolean of an `if` or `while` condition expression.

Answer (score 0):

`cin` is an instance of `istream` template class. `operator >>` acts on this istream instance  to load input into data and returns a reference to this `istream`. Then in `while` condition it is tested by a call to `cin::operator void*() const` (`explicit operator bool() const` in C++11) which invokes `fail()` function to test if operation succeeded. This is why you can use this operation in while condition

```
while ( cin >> x)
{
   //...
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type of `operator >>` for `std::istream` is `std::istream` again.  It returns the left-hand argument (`cin` in your case).  And `std::istream` has an `operator bool()` which enables using a stream in a conditional expression.  These two things together enable testing of a stream the same way we test many other C++ objects for validity, such as pointers.